# Invite users with AppInviteDialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am glad that Facebook finally let users invite their friends with the SDK version 4 but I don't know how to do it. The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android) is clear at least for a while:

```
if (appInviteDialog.canShow()) {
      AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
          .setApplinkUrl("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp.android")
          .setPreviewImageUrl("http://www.myapp.com/Images/stub.jpg")
          .build();
      appInviteDialog.show(MainActivity.this, content);
}
```

So far this couldn't be simpler. But once I select a user to invite I get Missing App Link URL error:

[image]

I understand I need to create an App Link URL, but I don't really know how. According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android#app_links) I should put meta tags between the `<head></head>` sections on the website associated with my Facebook app in the developer console's Settings/Site URL section.

So I put these on my website:

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="https://fb.me/1047359658624810" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="MyApp" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.myapp.android" />
<meta property="al:web:url" content="http://myapp.com" />
```

The `https://fb.me/1047359658624810` is created with the [App link generator](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host).

[This part](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content) is totally obscure. In the example the url is `sharesample://story/1234` and `sharesample` is defined as a scheme in an intent filter, but then what is `story/1234`?

In the App Link Generator

1. I added the intent filter to `AndroidManifest` with the scheme `<data android:scheme="com.myapp.android" />`
2. I set deep linking in the launcher class as

   `Uri targetUrl = AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());
   if (targetUrl != null) {
        Log.i("ACTIVITY", "App Link Target URL: " + targetUrl.toString());
   }`
3. I set the App Link Name as App Link URL for MyApp
4. I set the URL as the Google Play URL
5. I set the App Name as MyApp
6. I set the package name as com.myapp.android
7. Then I set the generated App Link URL on the website as

`<meta property="al:android:url" content="https://fb.me/1047359658624810" />`

For now all I need is to be able to send app invites and when users click on them they should be taken to the Google Play URL of the app. It's like I'm one step from finishing this thing but I can't figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to create your app url thorough facebook have a look into bellow url

How to create [App Link URL](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host)

It will show page like. You don't need to fill iOS information if your app is only for android

[image]

After filling required information click on next and it will generate App Link Url.

[image]

Use the generated url and cheers

Comment: What I didn't know was that this is the app link URL I need to set in the application itself and not the google play link! Also, I don't need any meta tags on the website. Thanks!

Comment: You can either put the meta tags on your website, and just use your website url as the app link url, OR you can create a URL using the tool above, and use that as the app link url. Both will work.

Comment: Is there someway to change how this appears as a post? I followed the same steps for sharing to Facebook, and it is working, but looks ugly as it displays fb.me post without any data.

Comment: It won't appear in post it will appear in notification list only. Can you share the screenshot?

Comment: this does not help at all if you need to pass a custom referral code and you need a web fallback for non-mobile users / platform you don't support. I've set my custom deep link URL in the al:android:url in the form myapp://my-string?myReferral=myref and I keep getting that error. The app is not released on Google Play (it's just in Alpha, only me can access). And I think I'm 100% compliant with facebook documentation still get the error message above.

Comment: @Daniele 
Did you figure it out.? I am using fb hosting api and still can't get referral to work

Comment: @Snake yes, I wasn't doing anything wrong. The problem was that Facebook caches every call, even those that return an error. The first time I tried there was an error in the page and Facebook cached it, It wasn't calling my server again. I had to input my URL here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to see what was going on and force a cache purge.

Comment: @DanieleSegato Thank you. I have a question. What do you put in the my-string portion. Do I put anything? Or should be fb id or something sepecifc

Comment: @Snake I've no idea of what you are talking about. No clue on what "my-string" portion is.

Comment: I am talking about the url you said in your comment 2 posts ago. You said you used myapp://my-string?myReferral=myref   . I was wondering what my string is

Comment: @Snake its whatever string you decide to use and intercept in your app :)

Comment: app link generator "404 Page not found"

Comment: app link generator "404 Page not found"